# sum from two tables insert if not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum, full-outer-join

I have a situation where I want to sum difference between two tables. problem is that a row can exist in the second table and then I want to insert it as new row.

Pseudo

```
SELECT T1.seller, T1.code, T1.amount - T2.amount
```

Look at the image for an explanation

[LINK](http://postimage.org/image/aj6sn3muf/)

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: `SELECT T1.seller, T1.code, (T1.amount - T2.amount) as TAmountSum from T1 inner join T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID`

Comment: Im using SQL2008
SELECT T1.seller, T1.shortcutcode, (T1.amount - T2.amount) as totalamount FROM Table1 T1
inner join Table2 T2 on T1.seller = T2.seller
But this gets duplicated rows

Comment: `SELECT distinct T1.seller, T1.shortcutcode, (T1.amount - T2.amount) as totalamount FROM Table1 T1 inner join Table2 T2 on T1.seller = T2.seller`

Comment: what is the tables columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 DECLARE @T1 TABLE(
    seller VARCHAR(10),
    code VARCHAR(3) NULL,
    amount MONEY
)

 DECLARE @T2 TABLE(
    seller VARCHAR(10),
    code VARCHAR(3) NULL,
    amount MONEY
)

INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES
('VL',NULL,1),
('VL','317',70005.6)

INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES
('VL',NULL,0.5),
('VL','500',4450)

SELECT seller,code,SUM(amount) [amount] FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM @T1
UNION ALL
SELECT seller,code,-amount as amount FROM @T2
) T
GROUP BY seller,code
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make a full outer join - then sum it up. If you run only the inner query you will get each possible row combination (exclusive in t1, exist both in t1 and t2, exlclusive in t2) - you then group it up and do the sum.

```
SELECT  Seller ,
        Code ,
        SUM(Tab1_amt - Tab2_amt) AS Amount
FROM    ( SELECT    COALESCE(tab1.Seller, tab2.Seller) AS Seller ,
                    COALESCE(tab1.code, tab2.code) AS Code ,
                    COALESCE(tab1.amount, 0) AS tab1_amt ,
                    COALESCE(tab2.amount, 0) AS tab2_amt
          FROM      tab1
                    FULL OUTER JOIN tab2 ON tab1.seller = tab2.seller
                                            AND tab1.code = tab2.code
        ) AS Tbl
GROUP BY Seller ,
        Code
```

See [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3084/6)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a `FULL JOIN` (unless you actually want the row inserting to the first table)

```
SELECT  COALESCE(t1.Seller, t2.Seller) AS Seller,
        COALESCE(t1.Code, t2.Code) AS Code,
        COALESCE(t1.Amount, 0) - COALESCE(t2.Amount, 0) AS Amount
FROM    Table1 t1
        FULL JOIN Table2 t2
            ON t1.Seller = t2.Seller
            AND COALESCE(t1.Code, 0) = COALESCE(t2.Code, 0);
```

If you do need the row inserting to table 1 you will need to do 2 operations, first insert, then select:

```
INSERT Table1 (Seller, Code, Amount)
SELECT  t2.Seller, t2.Code, 0 AS Amount
FROM    Table2 t2
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Table1 t1
            WHERE   t1.Seller = t2.Seller
            AND     COALESCE(t1.Code, 0) = COALESCE(t2.Code, 0)
        );

SELECT  t1.Seller, 
        t1.Code, 
        t1.Amount - COALESCE(t2.Amount, 0) AS Amount
FROM    Table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
            ON t1.Seller = t2.Seller
            AND COALESCE(t1.Code, 0) = COALESCE(t2.Code, 0);
```

**EDIT**

IF rows in each table are not unqiue and you need to sum them then you will need to do the sums in subqueries as the JOIN will introduce cross joining:

Consider this data

```
Table1
Seller  Code    Amount
VL      500     10
VL      500     20

Table2
Seller  Code    Amount
VL      500     30
VL      500     5
```

When you join this you will get:

```
t1.Seller   t1.Code t1.Amount   t2.Seller   t2.Code t2.Amount
VL          500     10          VL          500     30
VL          500     10          VL          500     5
VL          500     20          VL          500     30
VL          500     20          VL          500     5
```

The sum of the difference is then -10 instead of -5.

```
SELECT  COALESCE(t1.Seller, t2.Seller) AS Seller,
        COALESCE(t1.Code, t2.Code) AS Code,
        COALESCE(t1.Amount, 0) - COALESCE(t2.Amount, 0) AS Amount
FROM    (   SELECT  Seller, Code, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
            FROM    Table1 
            GROUP BY Seller, Code
        ) t1
        FULL JOIN 
        (   SELECT  Seller, Code, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
            FROM    Table2 
            GROUP BY Seller, Code
        ) t2
            ON t1.Seller = t2.Seller
            AND COALESCE(t1.Code, 0) = COALESCE(t2.Code, 0);
```

**EDIT 2**

The `UNION` method in [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13817111/1048425) will perform much better than the FULL JOIN:

```
SELECT  Seller, Code, Amount = SUM(Amount)
FROM    (   SELECT  Seller, Code, Amount
            FROM    Table1
            UNION
            SELECT  Seller, Code, -Amount
            FROM    Table2
        ) t
GROUP BY Seller, Code
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? your not telling what table to insert into "therefore tableX"

```
insert into tableX (seller,code,amount) values (T1.seller, T1.code, T1.amount -T2.amount)
select count(*) from table2 having count(*) < 1
```

notice you put the filter as a select statement after your insert to apply filter
you didn't specify what type of sql you need, so i cant say if this works